# How to get the generated GWT source code to run in DEV mode?

Tags: gwt, maven, gwt-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module GWT project built with Maven. I would like to have the generated GWT code (location specified by the [gen gwt:compile parameter](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#gen)) available for debug in DEV mode.

I launch DEV mode from an eclipse launcher.

However, when I try to add the generated code as a source folder in eclipse, I get a ton of errors which prevent the app from running. Even with the errors, I've tried to run my webapp with no success.

The majority of the errors are JSNI '*reference to non-existant field*' errors located in `*_TypeSerializer.java#loadSignaturesNative()` methods.

Other errors are due to the absence of generated CSS files from inlined UIBinder styles, and a couple of mismatched input parameters to `ImmutableMap_FieldSerializer.deserialize(...)` and `ImmutableMap_FieldSerializer.serialize()`.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Temporarily - I usually add the target/.generated folder as src code by editing project build path.

Comment: @SSR That is exactly what I'm doing to get the errors I mentioned. I've also tried adding every single GWT 2.5.0 jar to the build path as well. Same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the folder to the source tab of the launcher, not as a source folder to your project.

Comment: Yeah. That did it! I was having some issues with my unit cache getting corrupted, but that did the trick!!

Comment: OMG! I'm geeking out about the Editor framework now that I can walk the code!!